# Selected item isn't working KnockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-2.0

I'm new in KnockoutJS, and I'm getting some problems.

I don't understand why **selectedOf** isn't updated after the click.

Can someone spot what I'm doing wrong?

```
<div>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: Ofs">
        <li data-bind="text: Number, click: $root.selectOf" style="cursor:pointer"/>
    </ul>
    <strong>Item clicked: </strong><span data-bind="text: selectedOf.Number" />
</div>

<script type"text/javascript">
    var OfsModel = function (initialData) {
        //console.log(initialData);
        var self = this;
        self.CurrentState = ko.observable(initialData.CurrentState);
        self.Ofs = ko.observableArray(initialData.Ofs);
        self.selectedOf = ko.observable();

        self.selectOf = function (of) {
            //console.log(of);
            self.selectedOf(of);
            //console.log(self.selectedOf());
        }
    }

    var initialData = '{"Ofs":[{"Client":"A","Number":"1","Qty":10,"QtyRejected":5,"StopReason":"","ModifiedOn":"\/Date(1345732172456)\/","IsHighlighter":false,"SequencesAvailable":[{"Id":1,"Name":"Seq1"},{"Id":2,"Name":"Seq2"},{"Id":3,"Name":"Seq3"}],"SelectedSequence":null},{"Client":"B","Number":"2","Qty":20,"QtyRejected":0,"StopReason":"too much work","ModifiedOn":"\/Date(1345732172457)\/","IsHighlighter":false,"SequencesAvailable":[{"Id":1,"Name":"Seq1"},{"Id":2,"Name":"Seq2"}],"SelectedSequence":null},{"Client":"C","Number":"3","Qty":30,"QtyRejected":0,"StopReason":"","ModifiedOn":"\/Date(1345732172457)\/","IsHighlighter":false,"SequencesAvailable":[{"Id":1,"Name":"Seq1"}],"SelectedSequence":null}],"CurrentState":""}';

    var vw = $.parseJSON(initialData);
    ko.applyBindings(new OfsModel(vw));
</script>
```

EDIT:
I put the code on http://jsfiddle.net/muek/KBeZ3/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you access the `Number` property off of `selectedOf`, then you need to get to the value of the observable first by calling it as a function with no arguments like `selectedOf().Number`.

However, if you do this before `selectedOf` is populated, then it will cause an error trying to access `Number` off of an undefined value.

A nice way around this is to use something like the `with` binding to set the scope for the children of an element.  It also protects against null.  This would look like:

```
<div data-bind="with: selectedOf">
    <strong>Item clicked: </strong><span data-bind="text: Number" />
</div>
```

Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/ecDgD/

Alternatively you could create a computed observable for the `Number` value that protects against null or bind like `data-bind="text: selectedOf() ? selectedOf().Number : 'none'"`